# Streaming audio from microphone to network

Tags: ubuntu, audio, recording, streaming, vlc-media-player

I have the following problem:

I want to stream the audio I record with one machine to another machine in the same network. 
It seems that vlc is the best shot at the moment. I was able to stream a music file via vlc but streaming the audio from the microphone the same doesn't work.

*EDIT* If I enable play locally the captured sound is played. Even streaming to another instance of VLC on the same machine doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try the "capture device" on the emitting VLC, and it doesn't work, or do you want explanations on this one?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the *pulseaudio*. It should be installed in ubuntu by default. It can act as audio server. More details here: [PulseAudio](http://pulseaudio.org/wiki/AboutPulseAudio)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [shoutcast](http://www.shoutcast.com/download) server.